# Would it be possible to discover through linguistics if any non-human languages influenced known language families?

Tags: language-change, language-families, reconstruction

Suppose some recent hominins such as Neanderthal had a spoken language (currently, as far as I'm aware, we are uncertain if they did, but suppose we knew they did). If this were the case, would it be possible to uncover their influence on known language families through linguistics, or is the time gap so large that any influence would be essentially lost in the noise?

Comment: It's impossible to find a thing if you don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: @YellowSky If someone asks you to help them find their red ball do you tell them "I can't help you; I've never seen your ball before"? We may not have first-hand experience of a non-human language, but surely there are ways we could narrow down what we are looking for, unless as I said it is too deep in time to be recoverable.

Comment: For example, if we found certain qualities of a subset of a language that differed drastically from the normal construction for that language, and no other influencing factors are known, and the range of the speakers of that language overlapped the range of the Neanderthal, it might provide some interesting insights. I don't know if this level of detail is possible in linguistic analysis though, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that most if not all current languages have too much noise in them, but perhaps there is an old enough language that we have enough of preserved that this type of analysis is possible for--perhaps not.

Comment: English has acquired a range of words from non-human languages: baa, cock-a-doodle-doo, meow, moo, oink, quack, woof. Oh is it not April 1 any more?

Comment: "Results suggest that the evolutionary origins of human laughter can be traced back at least 16 million years to the last common ancestor of humans and  apes" .[Do apes laugh](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=104952197). Researchers have found signs of 2 genes that Neanderthals and modern humans might have shared: one *that's thought to confer language ability*, and another that makes adults unable to digest lactose in milk.(+Did humans-N'thals interbreed?)
[Scientists Finish First Draft Of Neanderthal Genome](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=100648070)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposal is complete science-fiction. Not only is it too far in time (and it is, by almost an order of magnitude, as the proto-language we know the most about was maybe spoken in 3500BC whereas the most studied recent Hominid group, *Homo neanderthalensis*, disappeared roughly 35,000 years ago) but the correct analogy would be to ask someone who is completely colorblind to find a slightly reddish ball in a mass of orange balls: the best we can do at present is trace (with great difficulty) the variation of Neanderthal's DNA in human populations. From this kind of data, it would already be extremely hard to get non-trivial results on the movements of populations leading to this distribution of Neanderthal DNA (especially as East Asian populations have the highest rate of Neanderthal DNA, quite counterintuitively, see for instance [here](http://www.genetics.org/content/194/1/199)). Of course, tracing the evolution of a delicate and transient cognitive and cultural phenomenon such as language is immensely harder than tracing population movements (for which we might at least hope to find archeological evidence). Not to mention the fact  that questions on mutual influences between well-recognized family of languages (such as indo-european and uralic for instance) are already far beyond the scientific consensus on the historical evolution of languages.

To recap: even considerably easier problems both in the study of the influence of other hominid groups on *Homo Sapiens* and on past mutual influences in languages are currently totally out of reach. The project described is presently about as scientifically credible as reaching the speed of light with a steam engine.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I expected, but since I don't have a lot of experience with linguistics I thought I'd ask!

Comment: You may rest assured that no non-human language influenced human language, because there is no known non-human language.

Comment: @jlawler I don't think we can be so confident of that: http://news.discovery.com/human/evolution/neanderthals-talked-like-us-130711.htm

Comment: @jlawler Unless you are referring to the fact that Neanderthals may be described as human, in which case I would clarify that by human I mean *Homo sapiens sapiens*.

Comment: @jlawler, "You may rest assured that no non-human language influenced human language, because there is no known non-human language." I'm not following your logic here... if there were such an language which had influenced human language, would we necessarily know about it?

Comment: Why do you consider counterintuitive that "East Asian populations have
the highest rate of Neanderthal DNA". If the Neanderthal population
has been declining, it could be that the earlier Cro-Magnon had more
opportunity to mix with them before spreading and occupying land
further east. Also, speculating without real knowledge, could it be
that early Cro-Magnon were genetically a bit closer, thus having
offsprings more easily. The Neanderthal migrated from Africa some 150,000 years
earlier, afaik. So 15,000 years could make a difference.

Comment: @babou If I had had to guess, my utterly uninformed prediction would have been that the highest rate of Neanderthal DNA would be found in or near the geographic areas formerly inhabited by Neanderthal, not 5000km from it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is very much the case. Just listen to the way some people
bark.  (belated April first contribution)

... and more seriously, it is most likely that some animal cries (is
that language) originated human words by imitation.  They can first enter
the language via onomatopoeias, and may later evolve on their own.

The best known example today is "tweet", but "bark" or "tchirp" could
probably qualify too. Though the origin of "bark" could be different.

Regarding real language, such as may have been spoken by Neanderthal
people, it is probably too far away in time, as was said.

Then there is the distinct possibility that intelligent communication
requires structures that are universal, not because we are all
similarly wired, but because that is what communication entails
(which would then cause us to be similarly wired).

If a non-human specie evolved language independently of us, it could
well be that their language structure would not surprise too much
human linguists. Then, if such beings had influenced human languages 5
or 10 thousands years ago, possibly less, it might not even be
detectable.

Comment: "Bark" is not onomatopoeia in English, it's just a verb like "speak" or "shout", and it can be traced back to proto-Indo-European. It's not "the dog went 'bark bark'" but "the dog barked" or "the dog went 'woof'".

Comment: @hippietrail I took the examples [on the
web](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/5-examples-of-onomatopoeia.html). I
did not say "bark" or "tchirp" are onomatopoeia, but that they could
be derived from one. Many turn into verbs or nouns. Of course I cannot
*mumble* this, or *hiss* it in your ears, even less *murmur* it,
because you are too far away. However the etymology of bark could also
trace it to older words for "break",... I have no opinion of my own on
this.

Comment: Actually I could be wrong. I'm looking it up [on etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bark) again and it doesn't say what I thought it said. They do say it was of echoic origin back in Proto-Germanic. It turns out I got my info [from the English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bark#Etymology_2) ...

Comment: @hippietrail As I said in my answer, the origin of "bark" as a verk is not clear. BTW what do they mean by "of echoic origin". I do not know this technical use of "echoic".

Comment: This use of "echoic" is pretty common in etymologies for describing words that started out as onomatopoeia, ie "echoing" sounds with the human voice.